# How to tell Typescript that *in this instance* a function's return type is never null

Tags: angular, typescript, strictnullchecks

I'm trying to get typescript `strictNullChecks` working in an Angular 5 project.

I have a form:

```
this.signinForm = this.fb.group({
  emailAddress: ['', NGValidators.isEmail()],
  password: ['', Validators.required],
  rememberMe: false,
});
```

I can get the `rememberMe` control using `this.signinForm.get('rememberMe')`. The return of the `FormGroup#get` method however, is `AbstractControl | null` so typescript doesn't like `this.signinForm.get('rememberMe').value` (because it thinks `this.signinForm.get('rememberMe')` could be null).

Is it possible to tell typescript that, *in this instance*, the return of `this.signinForm.get('rememberMe')` is always `AbstractControl` *and not* `AbstractControl | null`?

Comment: You can always wrap it with `as any or as AbstractControl` like `(this.signinForm.get('rememberMe') as AbstractControl).value`

Comment: @Szarik Awesome! That's exactly what I was looking for! If you post that as an answer I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `!` operator:

```
this.signinForm.get('rememberMe')!.value
```

Comment: I decided to make this the official answer because it provides a better solution to the question asked. Both answers are great / really helpful to know, however (and, obviously, both are valid answers to the question).

Answer (score 1):

We can force type in `TypeScript` by wrapping expression with `as [type]`. In your case it would be `(this.signinForm.get('rememberMe') as AbstractControl).value`.